# outputting all array values to file with php

Tags: php

Im working with a foreign API and im trying to get a fix on what all its sending to my file with the GET method.

How can i output something like `print_r($_GET)` to a file so i can read what all its sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Writing to a file:

You could use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to create the file with your output. This function will accept a string, or an array, which releases you of the burden to convert your array into a writable-format.

```
file_put_contents("myget.txt", $_GET);
```

As stated in the comments, this option isn't ideal for multidimensional arrays. However, the next solution is.

#### Maintaining format:

If you'd like to maintain the `print_r()` formatting, simply set the second parameter to `true` to return the value into a variable rather than outputting it immediately:

```
$output = print_r($_GET, true);
file_put_contents("myget.txt", $output);
```

Comment: Mind you though, that this will not write the items in $_GET as seperate lines. It will simply append every item in $_GET after the other without any newline character.

Comment: The first option does not work if you have nested arrays in $_GET like $_GET = array(
 'coord'=>array('x'=>'10', 'y'=>'10'),
 'speed'=>'10'
);

Answer (score 4):

If you have a hash, both of the listen solutions won't give you the keys. So here's a way to get your output formatted by print_r:

```
$var = print_r($your_array, 1);
file_put_contents("your_file.txt",$var);
```

The second option of print_r is boolean, and when set to true, captures the output.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need a log to store the `$_GET` variables being submitted to your script, for debug purposes. I'd do something like this *appending* values to the end of the file, so the file is not overwritten every request:

`file_put_contents('path_to_log.txt', print_r($_GET, true), FILE_APPEND);`